# File display using PHP and header() not working

Tags: php, header, readfile

I'm trying to show any file in the browser using PHP and headers, but it isn't working with a PNG image, it shows a strange black square like this:

[The Strange Blank Square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Sk2.png)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($filepath));
    readfile($filepath);
    die();
?>
```

I already checked the `$filepath` variable, its the full path (`E:\wwwPublic\myapp\application\controllers\..\..\documents\34807\image.PNG`) I don't know what is going wrong in that code.

Do you have any idea(s) ?

Comment: The strange black squares says that you are reading an image file. Aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I think this is what it means, but the blank square isn't the image I'm trying to read

Comment: is the header set before anything is sent to display to the page? (not even a doctype or html tag, nothing must be displayed to document at header time)

Comment: No, the source code only display the image data

Comment: if this is the only code in your php file, then `$filepath` is not defined. If this is included in another file, be careful that the file that inludes this must not have any display output before the include. Anyway, what do you get when you display `mime_content_type($filepath)` value?

Comment: you need to use the right header type.

Comment: Yes, I'm including it from Code Igniter, but there is nothing displayed on page before I call this, the `mime_content_type()` contains `image/png`

Comment: mmmh don't know then.. do you get the image when you call directly this file (with a static filename string, or $filename var assignment before the header)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I found that Code Igniter has default headers, I needed to add `ob_clean()` to remove all of them and add my own, Thank you for your help